# How to detect bumps via Apple TV Siri Remote

Tags: accelerometer, uitapgesturerecognizer, tvos

I'm unable to find any documentation relating to right and left *bumps* on the new Apple TV Siri Remote. You can see this in action at 1:00 of this video, [Hands On: Apple TV 2015 Bluetooth Touch, Motion & Siri Remote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WljmAKMj6a8).

[Remote and Interactions](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/remote-and-interaction/) mentions positional taps, but these *bumps* are triggered by the accelerometer, suggested by the video.

Are these *bumps* actually positional taps? How can I detect left and right *bumps*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tapping (without clicking the physical button) on the edges of the touchpad will synthesize a directional movement event, as described in the documentation link you provided.  You should be able to detect these with one or more `UITapGestureRecognizer` instances configured with the `allowedPressTypes` appropriate for the relevant edge(s).  Such a gesture recognizer will also recognize game controller dpad button presses and directional clicks from older Apple Remote devices.

The accelerometer-based action from the video should be achievable with the `GCMotion` API from GameControllerKit.